# SQL Query to fill column with combination of other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have table with this structure

```
ID | Parameter1 | Parameter 2  | Multiplication
1  |     1024   |     100      |
2  |     1200   |     200      |
3  |     1600   |     300      |
4  |     1900   |     400      |
```

I want to fill column Multiplication with combined string from Parameter 1 and Parameter 2

```
ID | Parameter1 | Parameter 2  | Multiplication
1  |     1024   |     100      |   1024_100
2  |     1200   |     200      |   1200_200
3  |     1600   |     300      |   1600_300
4  |     1900   |     400      |   1900_400
```

Help me please to create this SQLQuery

Comment: You can concatenate the strings, but how you need to do it depends on the server you are using - so which server are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using SQL then the following query should work..

Assuming the Param fields are ints use cast to make them strings

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Multiplication = CAST(Parameter1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + CAST(Parameter2 AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Else if they are already strings (e.g., varchar, text) just don't cast. I.e.,

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Multiplication = Parameter1 + '_' + Parameter2
```

Just change Table1 to the name of your table

Comment: Your second variant worked, but in very strange way. It fill last column in sum of first two columns, but all 3 columns are 'TEXT' columns. Also neither CAST or CONVERT didn't work, MySQL give error on them

Comment: Hrm it must be the MySQL syntax being a pain... have you tried @Michał Powaga's version?

Comment: Oh, this variant worked. date Table1 set
    Multiplication = concat(Parameter1, '_', Parameter2), but it's failed with 'cast' part. BTW i get all i want, thanks

Answer (score 6):

An alternate for SQL Server is to add a column to handle this for you. It will automatically update the value if either parameter1 or parameter2 changes:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD myJoinedColumn AS CAST(Parameter1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + CAST(Parameter2 AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Or as @Scozzard mentions in his answer, if they are already strings:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD myJoinedColumn AS (Parameter1 + '_' + Parameter2)
```

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL:

```
update Table1 set
    Multiplication = concat(cast(Parameter1 as char), '_', cast(Parameter2 as char))
```

More about [`cast`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) and [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) in MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual.

Answer (score 2):

```
update Table1 set Multiplication = CONCAT_WS('_',Parameter1,Parameter2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update tablename
set Multiplication = convert(varchar, Parameter1) + '_' + convert(varchar, Parameter2)
```