# Access 2010 merging 2 columns into a 3rd using SQL

Tags: sql, rdbms, ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 table with two columns; latitude and longitude. I want to create a third column called loc that combines both values into one and separates them with a comma like (latitude, longitude).

I have gotten this far which makes a select query:

```
SELECT ([latitude] & ", " & [longitude]) AS loc
FROM AllCountries;
```

This displays the intended result. However, I cannot copy this information into the third column. I tried appending it like this but I got key value errors for all records:

```
INSERT INTO AllCountries ( loc )
SELECT ([latitude] & ", " & [longitude]) AS loc
FROM AllCountries;
```

Any ideas how this can be done? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I assume column loc is already created with no values):

```
UPDATE AllCountries
SET [loc] = [latitude] & ", " & [longitude]
```

Comment: This returns blank rows with null value. I have created the loc column already and all three columns are set to contain numbers in the table design view.

Comment: @Karl: your **loc** column cannot be defined as number - it contains text now, as you connect two numbers with semicolon.

Comment: I changed it to text but the result is still null. When I ran the query I received a type conversion error for all records.

Comment: @Karl: although I don't have Access 2010, it's working in 2007 as I presented. In case 2010 has different behavior, you can try wrap `latitude` and `longitude` columns in query with `CStr()`, like: `Cstr([latitude])`

Comment: Thanks! I ran the preview after changing the loc field to text but saw from Microsoft that updates do not generate previews. So I ran the query again after changing the loc field to text and this time it worked.

Comment: From Microsoft: UPDATE does not generate a result set. Also, after you update records using an update query, you cannot undo the operation. If you want to know which records were updated, first examine the results of a select query that uses the same criteria, and then run the update query. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845036.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your third column should be varchar or string equivalent and you can cast your columns to merge

Reference :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9126375/1805210